# Show Delete options for iOS app content in Settings App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For some native apps (like videos) when you go into the Settings app > General > Usage > Manage Storage > An App, it shows the actual content and allows the user to delete it from there:

[image]

Like for videos, it shows the content in a table view, gives various information like size and allows the user to delete the specific content. Is there a way to do the same for a third party app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a difference between what native apps can do and what third-party apps can do.  Third-party apps can only expose limited settings controls - switches, text fields etc.  You cannot expose a file browser, for example.

You will need to provide file management capabilities in the app itself if this is required.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can get advantage of the settings feature creating a Settings Bundle. This tutorial helps to clarify how you should do that.

http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/ios-how-to-create-an-ios-settings-entry-for-your-app-using-settings-bundle/

Comment: Now you've read the question. However I still like Paul's answer because it goes over the limitations of your answer.